# Java: Encryption/Decryption of a File: Multiple Errors

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

Hello and thank you for reading my question.  I am working on a program that stores encrypted strings line by line in a file.  But I get multiple errors with the program I currently have, and at this point I just don't know how to fix it.

I get the error **Given final block not properly padded**, and also **Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher**

Here is the code:

```
package testing;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class encryptedTest{

ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
static String IV = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
File txt = new File("encrypted.txt");
FileOutputStream fileOutput;

public encryptedTest(){
    wordList.add("TestingTestingTesting"); //First line of encrypted text...If I add 4 characters I get an input error
    wordList.add("Test"); // Second line of encrypted text
    startEncryption();
}

public void startEncryption() {     
        try {
            String key = "This is the Key ";
            if(!txt.exists()){
                encrypt(key);
            }
            decrypt(key);
            encrypt(key);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
}

public void encrypt(String key) throws Exception {
    try{
        fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(txt);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < wordList.size(); i++){
        byte[] data = wordList.get(i).getBytes();

        SecretKeySpec spec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, spec, new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes()));

        byte[] textEncrypted = cipher.doFinal(data);
        fileOutput.write(textEncrypted, 0, textEncrypted.length);
        if(!(i == wordList.size() - 1)){
        fileOutput.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
        }
    }
}

public void  decrypt(String key) throws Exception {
    LineNumberReader  lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(txt));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(txt));
    lnr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);

    for(int i = 0; i < lnr.getLineNumber() + 1; i++) {      
    try{
            FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(txt);
            SecretKeySpec spec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");

            String encryptedText = br.readLine();
            byte[] bufferdReader = new byte[encryptedText.length()];
            bufferdReader = new String(encryptedText).getBytes();

            Cipher cipher;
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, spec, new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes()));

            byte[] decryptedText = cipher.doFinal(bufferdReader);

            System.out.println(new String(decryptedText));

    }catch(Exception exc){
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    lnr.close();        
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new encryptedTest();
}
}
```

The second line of the encrypted text works fine it goes through encryption then decryption.  But the first line is what is causing problems it currently gets a not properly padded error, and if you add 4 characters on to the string you get a Input length error.

I have been at this problem for many hours now just trying to get this code to work but nothing I try seems to work, if you could not already tell I am very new to encryption/decryption.  Any tips that you have or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Encrypted data is not text and should not be saved in a file named .txt.

Comment: @EJP What file extension would you recommend?

Comment: The extension is not the issue... the problem is you are inserting newlines into a binary file, which is just wrong.  Binary files don't have "lines" and can contain 0x0d and 0x0a bytes as part of the data. Trying to interpret them as line endings just corrupts the file.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I was able to rework the program to not use the lines as separators. Thanks.

Comment: In addition to what Jim Garrison said, you cannot use a `*Reader` to read a ciphertext, because a `*Reader` handles characters, but a ciphertext is inherently binary and doesn't correspond to a valid character encoding. You will lose some bytes when reading it and therefore corrupting your ciphertext. Use a `*Stream` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will keep that in mind!